# Organize code for multiple views – Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I'm making an ipad app that starts up with a start menu, which have 5 options (buttons). Each of those 5 have a menu and other buttons on it. Basically it's a lot of pages (UIVIews) and its a lot of code. I have always written everything in the same file.

My question is if I could have one separate file for each page, and how would I connect them to each other? Thanks

#### Edit:

I have tried connecting a subclass of UIView with the ViewController like this:

subclass of UIView:

```
@implementation MyView
- (void)commonMethod:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"hej");
}
```

ViewController.h:

```
#import "MyView.m";
```

ViewController.m:

```
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    MyView *mv = [[MyView alloc] init];
    [mv CommonMethod:self];
}
```

Im getting this error:

```
d "/Users/tonymichaelsen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3D-shaped_2-   geccnqnxajtjkvblfiasmfippyhx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/3D-shaped 2.app/3D-shaped 2" normal armv7
cd "/Users/tonymichaelsen/Documents/documents/Xcode-projects/3D-shaped 2"
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
setenv PATH   "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang    -arch armv7 -isysroot   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhone OS6.1.sdk -L/Users/tonymichaelsen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3D-shaped_2- geccnqnxajtjkvblfiasmfippyhx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos - F/Users/tonymichaelsen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3D-shaped_2-  geccnqnxajtjkvblfiasmfippyhx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist   "/Users/tonymichaelsen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3D-shaped_2- geccnqnxajtjkvblfiasmfippyhx/Build/Intermediates/3D-shaped 2.build/Debug-iphoneos/3D-shaped    2.build/Objects-normal/armv7/3D-shaped 2.LinkFileList" -dead_strip -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link- runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework  CoreGraphics -o "/Users/tonymichaelsen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3D-shaped_2-g   eccnqnxajtjkvblfiasmfippyhx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/3D-shaped 2.app/3D-shaped 2"


duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Cube in:
/Users/tonymichaelsen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3D-shaped_2-  geccnqnxajtjkvblfiasmfippyhx/Build/Intermediates/3D-shaped 2.build/Debug-iphoneos/3D-shaped      .build/Objects-normal/armv7/ViewController.o
/Users/tonymichaelsen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3D-shaped_2- geccnqnxajtjkvblfiasmfippyhx/Build/Intermediates/3D-shaped 2.build/Debug-iphoneos/3D-shaped  2.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Cube.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Cube in:
/Users/tonymichaelsen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3D-shaped_2-   geccnqnxajtjkvblfiasmfippyhx/Build/Intermediates/3D-shaped 2.build/Debug-iphoneos/3D-shaped   2.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ViewController.o
/Users/tonymichaelsen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/3D-shaped_2-  geccnqnxajtjkvblfiasmfippyhx/Build/Intermediates/3D-shaped 2.build/Debug-iphoneos/3D-shaped   2.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Cube.o
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
```

Comment: No it still doesn't work

Comment: ah, I tried changing the name of the class to MyView2, now in the `[MyView2 CommonMethod:self];` I get Ùnknown receiver, did you mean MyView?` Another MyView already seems to exist

Comment: "Another MyView aldready seems to exist" does not belong to the error message

Comment: I deleted my MyView classes and added a new one instead and named it Cube, I re-did all declerations with Cube but got the same error. I'll post the whole error in the question

Comment: That's because you do `#import "MyView.m";` instead of `#import "MyView.h";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could I have one separate file for each page?

Absolutely, it is up to you. Each view can have a different view controller behind it, or several views can share one view controller. Xcode gives you full control over what you want to do, letting you specify the classes behind your screens.

> How would I connect them to each other?

Perhaps the easiest way of connecting them would be with [*storyboard segues*](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/), because it lets you write no code at all. All the connections and interactions would be handled behind the scene by the Cocoa's storyboard infrastructure. All you'd need to do is connecting your buttons to something that does the actual work.

Comment: Thanks you, but I have already started making the app all programmatically and I would like to keep doing so. So do you know somewhere where it explains it or is it very complicated?

Comment: If you are doing it all programmatically, all you need to do is separating the code of each view into a separate file. In this case you may be better off with a single data-driven controller/view implementation, where the code "interprets" an array of structures that specify how many buttons to draw, what should their positions be, and what should be called when the button is touched.

Comment: I have edited the question to show I method I tried but I got an error. Can you please take a look?